# Getting "InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*>" while upgrading from Spring 4.x to 5.x

Tags: java, xml, spring, exception, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Spring 4.x to Spring 5.x but facing one issue. I have multiple spring xml configuration files in `META-INF\spring\abc\` directory. In `META-INF\spring\` directory I have `abc-context.xml` file which contains following line:

```
<!-- Spring Bean Profiles will ensure only one instance is loaded based on -Dinstance=[name] -->
<import resource="abc/*.xml"/>
```

When I run the application with Spring 4.x everything works fine. Excerpt from the logs:

```
DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Looking for matching resources in directory tree [C:\...\abc\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc]
DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [C:\...\abc\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc] for files matching pattern [.../abc/target/classes/META-INF/spring/abc/*.xml]
DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [file:.../abc/target/classes/META-INF/spring/abc/*.xml] to resources [file [C:\...\abc\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc\pqr.xml], file [C:\...\abc\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc\mno.xml], file [C:\...\abc\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc\xyz.xml]]
```

When I upgrade to Spring 5.x and try to run the application, I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [...\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc-context.xml]; nested exception is java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 88: ...\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc\*.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.load(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:130)
    at com.nomura.unity.stp.model.camel.UnityStpMain.createDefaultApplicationContext(UnityStpMain.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:390)
    at com.nomura.unity.stp.model.camel.UnityStpMain.main(UnityStpMain.java:81)
    at com.nomura.unity.stp.audit.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 88: ...\target\classes\META-INF\spring\abc\*.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.<init>(FileSystemResource.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.createRelative(FileSystemResource.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:393)
    ... 14 more
```

Can someone please help me understand why * is getting treated as illegal character here? Any solution?

PS: I know I can have multiple bean profile definitions and import the files accordingly but I do not want to do that because it would be an additional change for me in many (200+) applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution.

changing this

```
<import resource="abc/*.xml"/>
```

to this

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/abc/*.xml"/>
```

solves the issue.